# Put the caption and field next to other contact form 7

Tags: css, wordpress

I use contact form 7.

The html code from form:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div id="left">
        First name [text first-name]<br/>
        Last name [text last-name]<br/>
        How Did You Find Us? [text text-find-us]
    </div>
    <div id="right">
    Email [email* your-email] <br/>
    Phone [text your-phone]
    </div>
</div>

Subject [text* your-subject] <br/>
Message [textarea* your-message]<br/>
[submit "Send"]
```

How can I put the "First name" to be in the same line with the box of box text in which user type his/her first name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how Contact Form 7 renders html with those tags which are inside brackets.  You could possibly use CSS/HTML to position the items.

HTML:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div id="left">
    <span class="label">First name</span><span class="form-input">[text first-name]</span><br/>
    <span class="label">Last name</span><span class="form-input">[text last-name]</span><br/>
    <span class="label">How Did You Find Us?</span><span class="form-input">[text text-find-us]</span>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
    <span class="label">Email</span><span class="form-input">[email* your-email]</span><br/>
    <span class="label">Phone</span><span class="form-input">[text your-phone]</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#left {
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
}
div#right {
  float:left;
  width: 400px;
}
span.label {
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
}
span.form-input {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mediaguru/f1e68999/